# what to do if this error arised in TestNg framework is used in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

java: cannot access org.testng.annotations.Test
bad class file: /C:/Users/Aswini Roy/Downloads/testng jar/testng-7.6.0.jar!/org/testng/annotations/Test.class
class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org/testng/ITestListener has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), only recognizes version up to 52](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075884/org-testng-itestlistener-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java)

Answer (score 3):

TestNG of a version you're trying to use is compiled for Java 11. You project uses Java 8 so that it cannot load class that is compiled for a newer version of Java.

What you can do is to configure your project to use Java 11 SDK or downgrade TestNG version.