# org/testng/ITestListener has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), only recognizes version up to 52

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When I execute my test with testng.xml then it runs fine, but when I execute with pom.xml then got the ERROR:

> [ERROR] java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/ITestListener has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

My Java version: 1.8.0_333, and Apache Maven 3.8.4.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does this help at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi

Comment: ... the [front page](https://testng.org/) of the TestNG website says it has required Java 11 since version 7.6.

Comment: is there any solution (keeping java 8 rather than switch to java 11). because for selenium.

Comment: Use TestNG 7.5 or earlier if you really don't want to change JRE. Selenium will (surely) work with Java 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the [TestNG website says](https://testng.org/doc/):

> Requirements
>
> TestNG Upto v7.5: JDK 8 or higher.
>
> TestNG v7.6.0 and above: JDK 11 or higher.

So the possible solutions are:

1. Use an older version of TestNG than v7.6.0 if you want to use Java 8 as your development platform.  The TestNG version will probably be in your project's POM file.
2. Upgrade your development platform to Java 11 or later.
3. If you are feeling brave<sup>1</sup>, attempt to backport the version of TestNG (>= v7.6.0) that you are using to run on Java 8 (or older).

---

<sup>1 - This could be trivial or complicated.  You won't know until you try it.</sup>

Comment: yes ! I use older version 6.14.3 of TestNG and working fine. thanks a lot.

Comment: I changed testNg version from 7.6.0 to 7.5, worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

I got same issue, tried some ways, but the following things worked for me.

Here actual issue is with TestNG plugin "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/remote/RemoteTestNG"

Here I added testNG plugin from Market place then It was installed 7.8.0 version which was developed by using java 8+ I think, due that it even we used java 1.8(8) also showing that error.

Solution: Using following url copy 7.4.0 site and add using the following steps
https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/

1. Uninstall current TestNG plugin(7.8.0)
2. In eclipse -> Help-> Install new software-> Add -> Add repository->
   name: TestNG7.4.0
   location: https://testng.org/testng-eclipse-update-site/7.4.0
   continue installation.
   Thanks,
   Samba M

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me, when I copied one maven, testng project from another project.
I was just missing adding TestNG external library in Eclipse, which can be done with below steps:

1. Right click on the project in Eclipse
2. Go to Build Path
3. Select Add Libraries...
   And on the opened popup, Select TestNG->Next->Finish